# Why I get 'rdkit.six.moves' has no attribute 'cPickle' if I don't call it?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pycharm, anaconda, pickle

I `import pickle` instead of `from rdkit.six.moves import cPickle` in code because I read that cPickle is deprecated, then I get this error:

```
---> 39   _fscores = pickle.load(gzip.open('%s.pkl.gz' % name))

AttributeError: module 'rdkit.six.moves' has no attribute 'cPickle'
```

I don't understand why I get this error if I'm not calling `rdkit.six.moves.cPickle`.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it. It was a problem with Jupyter Notebook in Pycharm for Anaconda. I don't know what happened exactly, but I have changed the kernel and it worked.

I add the Jupyter Notebook label.